# Purpose and efficiency of remove() in Collection and Iterator interface

Tags: java, collections, iterator

In the large data sets, what purposes do Collection.remove(), Iterator.remove(), and Collection.removeIf() fulfill? Which method will be efficient in different circumstances?

Appreciate your guidance.

I am as Java student and trying to understand the nuances of these three methods and their efficiency levels. Does each of them outweighs their benefits against the other in different circumstances?

Comment: This cannot be answered because those are interfaces, they make no guarantee about what happens and with what time complexity. And remove vs removeIf are simply two entirely different methods, and it is obvious that if you want to remove items based on a condition that you should use the latter.

Comment: Start by reading the respective javadocs.  Then read them again.   The methods remove things from ... something ... in different ways. Their respective efficiencies depend on 1) what implementations you are using, 2) the precise task you are attempting to perform, and 3) how you are attempting to do it.   In short, your question is Too Broad to be answered.

Comment: As a novice, you are better served focusing less on efficiency and more on semantics and writing clear, correct code.  99.99% of the time, clear correct code is more than efficient enough.

Answer (score 1):

Given that they are interfaces, it's just describing the *what* (i.e. `someIterator.remove()` will cause the underlying data storage thing, whatever that might be, to remove the last thing that was returned by this iterator if possible). It does not describe the *how*, and 'can it be efficient' is fundamentally a *how* kind of question.

However, one might ask for a hypothetical case where this can be fundamentally faster than all possible ways to remove a thing from a data storage concept in any other way.

And that certainly exists. We need to look no farther than `java.util.LinkedList` and `java.util.ArrayList`.

Let's imagine we have a list that contains every 'counting word':

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); // or LinkedList
list.add("zero");
list.add("one");
list.add("two");
...
list.add("ninety nine");
...
list.add("one thousand and one");
list.add("one thousand and two");
...
list.add("nine hundred and ninety nine thousand, nine hundred and ninety nine");
```

and we want to do some removal on it.

### Let's remove a single item: 1001

We hate 1001 for some reason and want to get rid of it. We call `list.remove(1001)`.

#### `linkedList.remove(1001)`

A linkedlist consists if a list of simple nodes. Each node keeps track of 3 things:

- A pointer to the previous node. The first node in the list doesn't have one (`null`).
- A pointer to the next node. The last node in the list doesn't have one (`null`).
- A pointer to the object that is stored at this position.

A LinkedList is then simply a list that has a pointer to the first node, and the last node, and that's all you need.

To remove the 1001st element. linked list does this:

- Use its pointer to the first node. Ask it for its next node.
- Ask *that* node for *its* next node.
- repeat that process for 1001 steps.
- Now we have the right node.

That was a pricey operation! But now that we have the right node, it's trivial:

```
Node oneThousandAndTwo = this.next;
Node oneThousand = this.prev;
oneThousandAndTwo.prev = oneThousand;
oneThousand.next = oneThousandAndTwo;
```

Note that various books and tutorials like to state that 'removal in a linked list is `O(1)`. **This is highly misleading, bordering on a lie!** - because, sure, deleting itself is fast, but you need to get to the right node first. Only if that can be shortcut somehow, it's fast. LinkedLists in java can delete *the first* element very quickly (you don't need to spend 1001 steps to find the first node!), but not some node in the middle.

#### `arrayList.remove(1001)`

ArrayLists have, as the name suggests, a single array as underlying storage mechanism. Hence, to 'find' the right element to delete, the arraylist just has to do `backingArray[1001]`. That was easy.

But it is that easy because all elements are in the right order in that backing array. So, to remove something, you need to shift **everything** 'above' the thing you want to delete down by one:

```
for (int i = indexToDelete + 1; i < size; i++) {
  backingArray[i - 1] = backingArray[i];
}
size--;
```

That's what arraylist has to do. A *very* pricey operation indeed! That's 998999 steps or so.

### Remove the string "one thousand and one"

Let's try something a little different. Instead of removing the 1001st element, we want to remove whatever element has the text "one thousand and one". Yeah, you and I know it's index 1001, but the computer doesn't have a natural language processing system baked into it and it has no idea. There's nothing for it but to **find** the item in question and then delete it. Let's try it!

### `linkedList.remove("one thousand and one")`

We could simply call `.remove("one thousand and one")` but the story is very similar to `.remove(1001)`, so let's do it slightly differently and say that our search is actually user-supplied and pluggable. We store a predicate in a variable to represent it:

```
Predicate<String> verboten = w -> w.equals("one thousand and one");

/* first find the index to remove */ {
var it = list.iterator();
int index = 0;
while (it.hasNext()) {
  if (verboten.test(it.next()) break;
  index++;
}

list.remove(index);
```

This code is worse than it looks! It will take 1001 steps to find the string "one thousand and one", and we already established that `.remove(index)` *also* takes 1001 steps. We now need 2002 steps to do the job and that feels kinda daft. We could do it in 'just' 1001 though, because when we find the string "one thousand and one" we're already at the right node, so we should just use it instead of iterating from the start to get to the 1001 node a second time. You can't get at the nodes yourself but that iterator does have it (as a `private` field).

**Here is your answer #1: The iterator has a `remove()` method so that it can reuse its node**.

This is therefore only 1001 steps:

```
Predicate<String> verboten = w -> w.equals("one thousand and one");

var it = list.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  if (verboten.test(it.next()) {
    it.remove();
    break;
  }
}
```

ArrayList is kinda screwed - it's going to take 1 million steps no matter what (1001 to get to the right place, then whatever's left to shift everything 'above it' down by one).

Sounds like a big win for LinkedList but it really isn't - both of them needed a number of steps in the same order of magnitude as its total size.

To highlight how efficiency can really get tricky, let's go for the most interesting case yet:

### Delete everything that matches a predicate

Actually, it's not so much "one thousand and one" we despise. It's everything whose first 3 letters are equal to its last three. We hate "two hundred and two" just as much. We even hate "one" because it trivially starts with the same 3 letters as it ends with:

```
Predicate<String> verboten = w -> w.substring(0, 3).equals(w.substring(w.length() - 3));
```

Now we want to delete every verboten count from our list. Let's try it without removeIf, and write them as efficiently as we possibly can!

#### Remove verboten strings from `linkedList`

Our first intent might simply be:

```
for (String word : linkedList) {
  if (verboten.test(word)) linkedList.remove(word);
}
```

But [A] this doesn't work (modifying the list while you are iterating it causes a `ConcurrentModificationException`), but more imporantly, [B] if it *did* work it would take **in the ballpark of a trillion steps**. A million times a million. We need to loop one million times, and `.remove(someWord)` can take up to 1 million steps to remove a thing, as we saw before.

Hence, bad code. Let's do it right:

```
var it = linkedList.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  if (verboten.test(it.next()) it.remove();
}
```

Simple and quite effective - this takes only on the order of a million steps. We go through the list of linked nodes only once. For some nodes (any node whose value matches our 'verboten' test) we shuffle some pointers around to 'cut our node out' from between its neighbours, thus deleting it. Fantastic!

#### Remove verboten strings from `arrayList`

Hey, let's use the same code, right:

```
var it = arrayList.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  if (verboten.test(it.next()) it.remove();
}
```

Oh dear. This **also takes on the order of a trillion steps**. The problem is, where `it.remove()` on LinkedList is fast, on arraylists it is not - it has to shift all elements above it down. So, this loops 1 million entries and for a percentage of them, takes up to 1 million steps to downshift all things above it. We're back to `O(n^2)` behaviour. This really really will take on the order of **hours** (maybe days!) for a computer to do, whereas looping a million times is milliseconds, maybe even nanoseconds. Faster than human brains can even comprehend.

But, there *is* a way to do it very quickly. It's just a little more complicated. We have to realize that we just need to shift all elements down by 'X', where X is increment everytime we see a verboten value. Then at the end we truncate the list and voila, we're done:

```
int deleted = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
  String v = list.get(i);
  if (verboten.test(v)) deleted++;
  else list.set(i - deleted, v);
}

// remove the last element 'deleted' times.
for (int i = 0; i < deleted; i++) {
  list.remove(list.size() - 1);
}
```

This code takes only 1 million steps (`arrayList.remove(lastIndex)` is an extremely fast operation, even if the list is very large. Specifically removing the last item from an arraylist is easy).

So, if this is our answer, this is the fastest way and we should use this code for our linkedlist too!

### OH DEAR!

But that code is painfully slow on linkedlists - removing the last index is in fact horrible (takes 'list size' steps), so that's *over* a trillion operations. Ouch.

### `removeIf` to the rescue!

Fortunately, this:

```
list.removeIf(verboten);
```

is fast for either case. Because now we ask the list: Hey, **you** figure out how to do this quickly. ArrayList's implementation of `removeIf` uses our 'scan through and shift down everything that doesn't need to be removed, then truncate the list' operation that is fast for arraylists but slow for linked lists.

In the mean time, linked lists just loops through its chain of nodes once and cuts out anything that matches, which is fast for linked lists.

That's why you want all 3.

Because the alternative is to write:

```
if (list instanceof ArrayList) {
  .. our array list efficient code here ..
} else if (list instanceof LinkedList) {
  .. our linked list efficient code here ..
}
```

And even if you are willing to stomach having to rewrite that *everywhere* you want to take 'any kind of list', which is the point of interfaces after all, what happens if we come up with a different kind of list implementation? Now we need to go back through the **millions** of existing java projects out there and retroactively find all that kind of code and add another `else if instanceof` style clause to it all.

Hence, `removeIf` is an efficient solution to this problem, and it's a problem that you can't simply solve by relying on `iterator()`, `iterator().remove()`, `.remove(idx)`, and `.remove(value)`.

### STANDARD `LinkedList` DISCLAIMER

You might walk away from this lesson thinking that LinkedList is, or at least can often be, more efficient than `ArrayList`.

**That is an incorrect conclusion**. LinkedList is bad and should never be used unless you are smart enough to know enough to know this is one of the exceedingly exotic cases where it really is the right answer.

In practice, the costs inherent to using linkedlists have a lot to do with CPU architecture and a very basic algorithmic-complexity analysis of the code cannot help you figure out thoe costs. And computers are really, really fast - you need very large lists indeed (tens of thousands, minimum) for linkedlist to be faster even for academic perfect cases for it.

Even then, **if** LinkedList is a better answer than ArrayList, in those cases often some other datatype (such as a concurrent list, or an ArrayDeque, or a HashMap) are an *even* better answer. In other words, LinkedList, the best answer?

Almost never. So 'never', you might as well ban it from your java vocabulary until you've got 5 years of experience at least.

Comment: Thank you so much @rzwitserloot for your comprehensive answer. It is very insightful. I appreciate for your kind words as well. I am really encouraged to ask questions.

Comment: Thank you luk2302, Stephen C, Brian Goetz for your advices. I really appreciate that.

Comment: Great write up. Re: `LinkedList is bad and should never be used` I had never thought much about it, but I'm sure I've chosen Java's `LinkedList` 5 or fewer times in my almost 10 years of professionally using Java. I'm thinking the real answer might be 2 times. I can only remember 2 unusual cases where it made sense to use a LL. I've used tree structures, linked hashmaps, and queues more, and even those are extremely rare in everyday development.

Comment: New programmers sometimes get taken for a ride and misunderstand how it works, and e.g. pick `LL` for a silly reason (e.g. "Because I can't manage to write the data structure to avoid add/remove from front, _and_ I don't know about ArrayDeque for some reason", or "Because I thought e.g. `.add(someIdxInTheMiddle, elem)` is fast with an LL). Combine that with how you rarely need it for justified reasons and this gets you to my advice of: Just forget it exists. Odds you use it when its wrong are far, far larger than you writing bad code because you 'forgot' about LL's existence.

Comment: The concept of linked lists has its place, if you’re using a different programming language or not using Java’s Collection API. So the problem for beginners is that they likely are taught the *concept* of linked list, followed by starting to use Java practically and it’s not obvious how the conceptual advantages of linked lists do not apply to Java’s specific implementation class `LinkedList`.